# How can one compute the cumulative distribution function of $\max (E -6,0)$, where $E$ is uniformly distributed?

Tags: probability-distributions

Let $E$ be uniformly distributed between $0$ and $10$. The cumulative distribution function of $\max(E-6,0)$ is: $$F(x) = \left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  0  & \mbox{if } x < 0 \\
        \frac{6+x}{10} & \mbox{if } 0 \leq x \leq 4  \\
  1 & \mbox{if } x > 4
 \end{array}
\right. $$

How does one arrive at this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $X = \max(E - 6, 0)$. Because $X \geqslant 0$, for any $x < 0$, there is $P(X \leqslant x) = 0$.

For $0 \leqslant x \leqslant 4$,\begin{align*}
P(X \leqslant x) &= P(X \leqslant x \mid E \leqslant 6) P(E \leqslant 6) + P(X \leqslant x \mid E > 6) P(E > 6)\\
&= P(0 \leqslant x \mid E \leqslant 6) P(E \leqslant 6) + P(E - 6 \leqslant x \mid E > 6) P(E > 6)\\
&= P(E \leqslant 6) + P(E - 6 \leqslant x, E > 6)\\
&= \frac{6}{10} + \frac{x}{10} = \frac{x + 6}{10}.
\end{align*}

For $x > 4$, $P(X \leqslant x) \geqslant P(X \leqslant 4) = 1 \Rightarrow P(X \leqslant x) = 1$.